# Using Crystal Report to print an Invoice

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

Is it possible to retrieve data from multiple tables in a LINQ-to-sql  database to form an invoice using a crystal report

Note that i am using C# visual studio 2010 and LINQ to sql Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crystal Reports can work with either a data object (such as a dataset or datatable) or an actual database, else well as with XML, so yes it can.

Note there's no such thing as a LINQ-to-sql database, LINQ provides a middle man between you and the database.  You probably mean you use LINQ to talk to your database and want to pass the results on to Crystal.

You can do this by converting the results to either a list or a dataset.

Comment: well that was great but another question is it doable to retrieve results from multiple table to the same report ? as i will start in it right now :)

Comment: A report can only contain one detail section, but it can contain subreports, which allow you to display multiple results.